# Add Subreport to a Crosstab main report in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, report, crosstab, subreport

I'm working on a project that specifically requieres a crosstab in the main report (variable amount of columns), in which, as crossed values, I've got the result of a sum.

But I need to display the details of such sum. I'm not using BusinessObject Enterprise, so there is no chance of linking to another report, and I can't drill-down on it, so the only way around seems to be the use of subreports.

Comment: Crosstabs are self-contained objects and fully dynamic so adding anything to them is going to be difficult. You say you've got dynamic columns, but what about rows? If you've got a small number of set rows you could try to manually place on-demand subs at those row locations.

Comment: That's not gonna work either. Rows are in the number of several hundreds. Also, it requieres subtotals. And the number would fluctuate even more often than the columns...

I just can't see any possibility of not using crosstabs.

Is there any way to implement anything on crosstabs that could solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only advice I have is to try to create the report without crosstabs or try to fit the "drilled-down" data into the crosstab itself. You won't be able to embed a subreport in the crosstab.